# Sync Two Inputs using add / minus button using Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, synchronization

I just want to asked if someone knows how to sync the two inputs while incrementing or decrementing it's value. Every Add / Minus(Using Bootstrap), the input value will sync to the other input value with the same name.. Or a Manual Add / Minus JS

Comment: What are the add/minus buttons you're referring to? Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML and any JS associated with those add/minus buttons.

Comment: Now Im using Bootstrap.. but if there's a way we can manually sync two inputs values while incrementing/decrementing it much better.. Thanks for the reply. Godbless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep inputs in sync they can share a variable for their value. Get a handle on the inputs fields and update their value to the variable.

Here is a quick example:

```
var one = document.querySelector('input#one');
var two = document.querySelector('input#two');
var add = document.querySelector('button#add');
var subtract = document.querySelector('button#subtract');
var value = 0;

function updateInputs() {
  one.value = value;
  two.value = value;
}

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  value += 1;
  updateInputs();
});

subtract.addEventListener('click', function() {
  value -= 1;
  updateInputs();
});

updateInputs();
```

Comment: @Jun if I understand you correctly, you're just asking to duplicate the exact same thing on the buttons. This isn't a very sustainable way of doing it, but I can demonstrate it by simply adding two more buttons, binding to their click events, and calling the same add/subtract functions as before: http://jsfiddle.net/hd5mueza/

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help! Got it now :) Thanks a lot! Can't vote to your comments due to my low reputation but this is a +1

Comment: @Jun no problem, you can vote on my answer if this answered your question.